# How to inverse $(I + \alpha M)$ for all $\alpha$

Tags: matrices

I am looking for a way to solve the following equation:

$$(I + \alpha M)X=F$$

$\forall \alpha \in R$ (the real domain), with $M$ a square complex matrix without any particular properties, $I$ the identity matrix, $F$ a complex vector and $X$ the unknown.

Thank you,

Comment: Suppose $\alpha=-1$ and $M=I$.